# Function to find a character in a string

Tags: c

```
int charfind(char* str, char c, int start) {
    int index = -1;
    for (size_t i = start; i <= strlen(str); i++) {
        if (str[i] == c) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

I've tried changing the parameters to unsigned chars and ints, and I've tried to feed it both character literals and the numbers of the ascii characters, but it always returns a -1.

That would seem to suggest to me that the if statement never evaluates to true.

Comment: It works for me: https://ideone.com/ght31m Please post a [mre].

Comment: `i <= strlen(str);` goes one beyond the end. You want: `i < strlen(str);` But this is slow because `strlen` (usually) must rescan the entire string on each loop iteration. Better is: `str[i] != 0;`

Comment: Do you know about the Standard Library function `strchr()`? While it's good to try to write your own version, it's better to use standard functions that have proven their worth for 50 years... (Kudos for using `size_t i = ...` instead of `int i = ...`)

Comment: @CraigEstey "`i <= strlen(str);` goes one beyond the end. " does **not **go 1 beyond what it should.  Consider `charfind(str, '\0', 0)`.  `strchr()` behaves that way too.

Comment: @mlb0066, "I've tried to feed it both character literals and the numbers of the ascii characters, but it always returns a -1" --> post sample input.

Answer (score 1):

You've not shown how you use this function. If the caller is behaving well and not passing garbage values, what you've written *should* work.

For your interest, here is another alternative:

```
int charfind( char *str, char c, size_t idx ) {
    if( str == NULL || c == 0 )
        return -1;

    for( ; idx && *str; idx-- )  // cautiously advance to start position
        str++;

    for( ; *str; idx++ ) // while not at end of string
        if( *str++ == c ) // if characters match
            return idx; // early termination

    return -1; // not found
}
```

Note that the 3rd argument is now `size_t` type. It would be unwise for a beginner to pass a memory address and allow the possibility of a negative offset.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to create a function to find a character in a string in C. What am I doing wrong?

**Good to test until `<= strlen()`**

That is what `strchr()` does.  "The terminating null character is considered to be part of the string.".  This allow `charfind(s, '\0', 0)` to return a non -1 result.

**Wrong type compare**

`str...()` functions acts as if the characters were `unsigned char` even if `char` is *signed*.  Recommend the same here.

**Overly complex interface**

`int charfind(char* str, char c, int start)` makes littles sense as the caller could have called with `charfind(str + start, c)`

**`int` vs. `size_t` indexing**

String length can exceed `INT_MAX`.  `size_t` is the best type for string indexing.

Consider `long charfind(char* str, char c, size_t start) {`.

Yet this is moot if the unneeded `start` parameter is dropped.

**Return value**

Rather than `int`, consider returning a pointer to the located position or `NULL` if not found.

If stuck with an index, consider wider type.

**Avoid repeated calls**

Rather than `strlen()` each time in the `for()` loop, perhaps

```
while (*str != c && *str != '\0') {
  str++;
}
if (*str == c) {
  return str;
}
return NULL;
}
```

**Use `const`**

This allows usage with `const` strings.

---

All together (and still returning a position index)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
long charfind(const char *str, int c, size_t start) {
  long position = -1;

  // Search 0 to start-1 for a null character and hope to not find it
  // as that means string is long enough to find a match.
  if (memchr(str, '\0', start) == NULL) {
    unsigned char uc = (unsigned char) c;
    const unsigned char *ustr = (const unsigned char*) str + start;

    // Search until match found or end of string.
    while (*ustr != uc && *ustr != '\0') {
      ustr++;
    }

    // Did above loop stop due to a match?
    if (*ustr == uc) {
      position = (long) (ustr - (const unsigned char*) str);
    }
  }
  return position;
}
```

Comment: @Fe2O3 Thank-you.  Answer amended.

Comment: @0___________ Sure, answer amended.

Answer (score 0):

It works. The only change I would suggest is the `for` loop condition. In your code `strlen` will be called on every iteration. Also, the condition should be < as you are not looking for the C string terminating char.

```
int charfind(char* str, char c, size_t start) 
{
    int index = -1;
    for (size_t i = start; str[i]; i++) {
        if (str[i] == c) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Kfs8hvW5d

You can also add some checks:

```
int charfind(char* str, char c, size_t start) 
{
    int index = -1;
    if(str && start < strlen(str))
    {
        for (size_t i = start; str[i]; i++) {
            if (str[i] == c) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```